# Can it be claimed there were Bulgarians in the Balkans before 681 AD?

Tags: early-medieval, the-balkans, bulgaria

In 680 Bulgar tribes under the leadership of [Asparukh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparukh_of_Bulgaria) moved south across the Danube and settled in the area between the lower Danube and the Balkan, establishing their capital at Pliska.

A peace treaty with Byzantium in 681 AD marked the beginning of the [First Bulgarian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgaria). The Bulgars gradually mixed up with the local population, adopting a common language on the basis of the local Slavic dialect.

Thus, the earliest and official date of Bulgarians on the Balkan Peninsula is at the end of the seventh century, however, according to [The Ravenna Cosmography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenna_Cosmography) compiled by an anonymous cleric in Ravenna around the sixth century:

[image]

The label *Bulgari* on the same Balkan area:

[image]

Now, the existence of [Old Great Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Great_Bulgaria) dates back to (at least) 632 AD  <sup>(if we don't consider the [Nominalia of the Bulgarian khans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalia_of_the_Bulgarian_khans))</sup>and its location is on the Western [Pontic–Caspian steppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontic%E2%80%93Caspian_steppe) which is far away from the [Balkan Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkans).

### Question

Having this in mind, **could it be claimed that there were Bulgarians in the Balkans long before the *"...Bulgar tribes under the leadership of Asparukh moved south across the Danube in 681 AD..."*?**

Comment: I hope you realise that this map is a modern interpretation of the Ravenna Cosmography. The Cosmography is a prose text and does not contain any maps.

Comment: @fdb Yes (and thank you for the clarification), this is a visualisation based on (if I'm not mistaken): https://archive.org/details/ravennatisanonym00geoguoft

Comment: You'd have to go through Romania first so I doubt it. More than like Romania "introduced" Southeastern Europe to their new friends....

Comment: Also according to Wikipedia, the cosmography was compiled around 700 AD, not in the sixth century.

Comment: @Spencer - It seems that the problem of the map is clear, as user fdb commented. What about the `plenty of other Latin and Greek sources mentioning Bulgarians living on the Balkans before 7th century` mentioned in the answer? Can they switch the answer to the question to "yes"?

Comment: @DoctorZhivago - What if they went through "Romania"? What has that to do with this question?

Comment: I guess in English the question title should say "Bulgars" instead of "Bulgarians".

Comment: @cipricus _Your_ answer is correct.  But it seems the sources in the other answer are being interpreted to mean something they don't.

Comment: @Spencer - I understand that the line of argumentation there is dubious. But correcting the interpretation of sources: can we answer "yes, Bulgars (proto-Bulgarians) have been present in the Balkans — only they were not able to settle there — before Asparukh,"? - By the way, I have a new question [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61942/37321)..

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

If by "Bulgarians" you understand ***Slavic people living south of the Danube around the Balkan mountains (today's Bulgaria)***, then yes, such people already existed there — and not only there (and there not only them) — about 60-70 years before Asparukh, but under a different name in a country that was called differently.

— Otherwise: no.

---

### Longer answer:

`could it be claimed that there were Bulgarians in the Balkans long before the "...Bulgar tribes under the leadership of Asparukh moved south across the Danube in 681 AD..."?`

Claiming that would be very odd, even absurd. But not completely absurd.

For that we have to forget about those maps. Arguments based on them are not only dubious, but useless. The name “Bulgar” entered Europe with the Bulgar Oghur Turkic invaders, and the date of their first invasion is not a matter of doubt. The country they conquered in the Balkans was called Bulgaria because of them and only after their coming there. After that, the Slavic-speaking people already present there started being called “Bulgars” too, and the present Bulgarians are much more the descendants of *those* Slavic people. So, in a sense *those* "Bulgars" or "Bulgarians" were indeed present in Bulgaria before Asparukh, only **they were not called that**, but simply Slavs. They are the ones that in spite of being conquered have finally imposed their language, because they were much more numerous. Thus, **present Bulgarians are closer to them than to Asparukh’s people**.

I could make a comparison to the case of Romanians. Wallachia and Moldavia had been occupied by [Cumans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumans), and Wallachian ruling dynasty as well as first polities there might be related to them. But they didn't endure enough to give their name to the country. By the time the Romanian states were created Cuman prestige had faded away enough so that the countries got other names ([Wallachia from the name of those speaking a Romance language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walhaz), Moldavia from a [river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Moldavia_and_Moldova#Etymology)). Had Cumans been as successful as the Bulgars, we might be calling the Romanians “Cumans” these days, the way some Slavic-speaking people are called “Bulgarians” and some Romance-speaking are called “French” (from Franks). Had the Bulgars been as unlucky as the Cumans, the Slavic — and more numerous — people they occupied might have imposed their name onto the country, the way Slovaks and Slovens did. — On the other hand it is worth mentioning that at the time of the Bulgarian empires a lot of Slavic-speaking people (what we now would call "Bulgarians") lived north of the Danube, while a lot of Eastern-Romance-speakers (probably descendants of Latinized Thracians, close to present "Romanians") lived south of the Danube (these, at political level, as well as Cumans, at military level, were very important in the restoration of the [second Bulgarian empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Bulgarian_Empire)). The "mixture" of neighboring peoples is usually rather similar; the language difference may be more or less related to that, and may have various causes.

---

Otherwise, this question seems like asking if there were any  “French” in Gauls before the Franks, or "Russians" in Russia before "the Rus".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are numerous sources pointing to Bulgarian people in this region long before the officially accepted 681 year. You can check [Saint Jerome's map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_Saint_Jerome_-_Mesia_hec_%26_Vulgaria.jpg) who lived in 4th century. On the map there is a label - Mesia hec & vulgares which is roughly translated as Moesia here also Bulgaria.

The map is a copy from 12th century which is used as an excuse to claim that this was added later. Note that the authenticity of the copy is not questioned and during the 12th century Bulgarian lands are under Byzantine rule and Bulgaria does not exists as a country.

But even without this map, there are plenty of other Latin and Greek sources mentioning Bulgarians living on the Balkans before 7th century. [Here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=18Z3t9Fm6sWPyHUbf9VZbV-W_3rg&hl=en_US&ll=44.95049060964214%2C24.546174324982864&z=6) you can check some of these sources.

You can also check [this genetic study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3590186/) from 2013 which brings forth some very interesting questions about who exactly are the ancestors of modern day Bulgarians.

And because people tend to ignore external links, I will add some citations:

Marcellinus Comes: [The Chronicle of Marcellinus](https://books.google.bg/books?id=SNMuDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR29&hl=bg&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q=Mundo%20Illyricianae%20utriusque%20militiae%20ductor&f=false)

```
(A. C. 530.) Ind. VIII, Lampadio et Oreste coss. Mundo Illyricianae utriusque
 militiae ductor, dudum Getis Illyricum discursantibus primus omnium Romanorum ducum 
incubuit, eosque haud paucis ipsorum interemptis fugavit. 
His autem deinde coss. idem dux audaciae suae secundus in Thraciam quoque 
advolans, praedantes eam Bulgares feliciore pugna cecidit, quingentis eorum 
in praelio trucidatis
```

This can be roughly translated as :

```
(year 530) Mundo, the master of the Illyrian soldiery, was the first Roman
 general to set upon the Goths who had previously been traversing Illyricum 
and put them to flight, after quite a few of them had been killed. However, 
later in this consulship, this same leader, fortunate in his boldness, 
hastened into Thrace and also killed, by fighting bravely, the Bulgars who 
were plundering it; five hundred of them were slain in the battle.
```

or this one from [The Chronicles](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/marcellinus1.html) again:

```
(499) VII. Ioannis Gibbi solius
1 Aristus Illyricianae ductor militae cum quindecim milibus armatorum et cum 
quingentis uiginti plaustris armis ad proeliandum necessariis oneratis contra 
Bulgares Thraciam deuastantes profectus est. Bellum iuxta Tzurtam fluuium 
consertum, ubi plus quam quattuor millia nostrorum aut in fuga aut in 
praecipitio ripae fluminis interempta sunt.
```

This can be translated as

```
(year 499)Aristus, the leader of Illyria went with 15k soldiers and the
 appropriate weaponry against the Bulgarians who were devastating Thrace.
 The battle took place at Tzurtam river where more than 4k of our soldiers 
died either while running or jumping from the high river bank.
```

And it is not only Marcellinus Comes, there are also Anastasius Bibliothecarius, Jordanes, John Malalas and others. And while their records do not show firm Bulgarian establishment it is quite clear that Bulgarians have frequented Thrace long before 681.

So obviously I cannot agree with other answers that the date when Bulgarians came on their present day state is well established. It is not. Also we cannot talk about Slavs during 5-8 century. Present day people living on this land never called themselves Slavs. This term appeared much later (16-17 century) to describe all people using Cyrillic alphabet and of course they do have something in common, but this is an entirely another discussion.

Comment: "Hec et vulgares" is Latin for "and these folk"  - there's no evidence of a connection to the Bulgars.

Comment: @Spencer what about the rest of the sources?

Comment: @Zeizi The Google Maps thing just looks like a bald assertion.

Comment: @Spencer, this meaning of just folks does not make sense. This is not a meme map saying "here be dragons", this is a map of Saint Jerome. It's the equivalent of contemporary map saying here live some folks. Yes, It may describe more than one tribe, but it definitely describes a group of people with some common denominator.

The "bald assertion" for Google Maps is actually grouped links to Latin and Greek sources mentioning Bulgarians on the Balkans long before 681. You can't find anything more valid than that.

Comment: Also I would be very glad if you share with us your translation of this quote from the chronography of 354: "Ziezi ex quo Vulgares."

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=slxbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=mesia+hec+et+vulgaria) says that the "Jerome map" was made in 1200, where they updated the description of Moesia.

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that the map is a transcript from 12th century and this is used to claim that this mentioning was not in the original. I've also pointed out that during 12th century Bulgaria does not exists as a country, leaving to the reader to decide who has the incentive to claim there are Bulgarians in Moesia and why.

I've also provided other sources.

Comment: Although the Byzantines occupied the area we call Bulgaria in the 12th Century, This was between the First Bulgarian Empire and the Second Bulgarian Empire, so it is reasonable to assume there were Bulgars there during that time.

Comment: If this map were the only source mentioning Bulgarians in the region before 681... but it isn't.

Comment: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61942/37321

Comment: It seems that genetic article you linked  is sheer propaganda. https://history.stackexchange.com/a/61946/37321 : `Studies done for that on Bulgarians show them most closely related to other Slavic peoples, and particularly most closely related to other southern Slavs. ...As for the "new studies" on the ancient Bulgar language mentioned in that paper ... I'm afraid this is one of those unfortunate situations where scientific study runs afoul of a country's local right-wing nationalist dogma.`

Comment: `...such views are based on anti-Turkish sentiments and the presence of Iranian words in the modern Bulgarian is result of Ottoman Turkish linguistic influence`

Comment: `It is particularly silly in this case, because that language did not in fact die out without issue. The Bulgars who stayed behind on the Volga did not magically disappear. The Chuvash language is descended from the Old Bulgar they spoke, and it is still spoken by 1.6 million people in Russia. It is solidly classified as a Turkic language, and back when that classification was in doubt, the other contender (Finno-Ugric) was not Indo-European either.`

Comment: I am not sure what your point is? Propaganda about what? Is the genetic data somehow skewed, or is the problem in linking it with modern linguistic tendencies and disputes? I am no language expert and it is hard to trace the roots of modern Bulgarian language, because probably it is heavily influenced and mixed between indigenous and migrating groups during the centuries.

My guess is that you try to suggest that Proto-Bulgarian influx was marginal. Well we do not have actual numbers but this seems highly unlikely. We know that Nikephoros I gathered all the military he can against Asparuh's

Comment: army and still has been defeated. Also obviously Asparuh's army and people were enough to negotiate with local tribes on equal terms, and even to actually be the ruling class and to give their name to the official state.

Nowadays it is generally accepted by Bulgarian historians that Proto-Bulgarians must have been significant enough in number although concrete information is lacking.

Comment: BTW sorry but arguing that scientific study is propaganda based on wiki citations and stackoverflow comments by anonymous people is anything but scientific.

Comment: I don't contradict genetic ancestry but its interpretation.We have to choose between contradictory statements depending on their credibility. The lack of Turkic ancestry in present Bulgarians is a fact and not a matter of dispute. The article you linked lacks credibility: it concludes that *the proto-Bulgars were not Turkic*. That conclusion is based on a second premise that *proto-Bulgars had greatly contributed genetically to modern Bulgarians ancestry*. That is not proven at all. The bibliography for that is not credible.

Comment: The fact that present Bulgarian lack Turkic ancestry can be interpreted in two opposite ways:(1) they have little proto-Bulgar ancestry OR (2) the proto-Bulgars were not Turkic. There are a lot of proof against (2) and very little in its favor. The fact that military power of invading barbarians was in most cases not reflected in the genetic pool of present Europeans is not a surprise, and Bulgarians are not an exception. Hungarians, Bulgarians and Romanians are almost identical at that level, they differ only linguistically.

Comment: The presence of Persian (Indo-European) influences in the language of the Cumans and Proto-Bulgars doesn't make them less Turkic. Even Hungarian has that influence, and also Ottoman Turkish was full of Persian terminology. The name of Asparukh comes from a Persian root ('aspa') meaning 'horse', but that doesn't mean he was fully "Persian". The same term entered Ottoman language and lead to "Spahi", the cavalry. The other way around, the name of the Bulgarian [Assen dinasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asen_dynasty#Etymology) and that of the Wallachian Bassarab dynasty are Cuman-Turkic.

Comment: Cumans played for Romanians almost the same role as proto-Bulgars for Bulgarians of the first empire: but because they were destroyed by the Mongols or run to Hungary they left few traces among the Romanians. If they had endured 100 years more maybe Romanians would be called Cumans now. But (even more than the the Vlach) Cumans were *decisively*  important in helping the Bulgarians restore their second empire against the Byzantines and then in beating the Latins. These Turkic peoples were very important militarily and politically, but not so much  genetically and linguistically.

Comment: I consider that the goal of reducing all Turkic elements of Bulgarian identity is extremely nationalistic. The same nationalist agenda demands that identification with the glorious proto-Bulgar state-builders should be enhanced (even by playing down the Slavic element). *Denying their Turkic identity is not the result of some objective research, but promoted in view of the anti-Turkish nationalistic goal. That is propaganda disguised as science*. (By the way, if you want me to see your comments, address me with @ or post comment under my posts.)

Comment: @cipricus, I agree with quite a few of your facts, but not with all. And I do make different conclusions. I posted the genetic research mainly to show that according to it, roughly 40% of the male descendants of contemporary Bulgarians seems to be autochthonous. No Proto-Bulgarians, no Slavic but local people dating back thousands of years B.C. The majority of the remaining 60% seems to be two groups, probably Proto-Bulgarians and the so called Slavic people. By the way genetic studies show that Slavic people are really more like cultural thing and not an ethnicity. The Turkic ancestry

Comment: of Proto-Bulgarians is just one of the many theories simply because we do not know much. And when we talk about language, how do you know what was the language of Proto-Bulgarians? We judge by today's Bulgarian language linking to old written sources. But again, if Proto-Bulgarians managed to leave trace in the language of the local people, then it is highly unlikely they were insignificant in numbers. And anyway, I have seen theories linking Bulgarian language and thus Proto-Bulgaians to various different ancestors and languages. This is highly disputable topic and a lenghty discussion.

Comment: and frankly is deviating from the question of the author. The mere fact that in my answer I give a bunch of Latin and Greek sources pointing out that there were Bulgarian raids In Thrace centuries before the currently accepted year and no one is able to meaningfully comment on it speaks volumes. At the very least translation is hard to come by, even the sources are not easily available(originals kept in various museums) and it contradicts what people are currently thought and know about these events. At the same time it gives us valuable information which we should not ignore.